# displaying a value in array of a table that has duplicate column value php

Tags: php, mysqli

this may be easy for some of u but I am really having hard time how to do it.

So I have here a code:

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "db_lms";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$query = $conn->query("SELECT course_id from enrol group by course_id having count(*)>1");


echo $query->num_rows;

?>
```

It can echo the number of those that have duplicated value 'course_id'.

Problem: My problem is how can I display those 'course_id' distinctively? I've been searching everywhere but found nothing.

[image: here is my table]

Basing from my table, my desired output should be: "1, 2, 8" because these are course_ids that have a duplicate.

I tried this:

```
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT course_id from enrol group by course_id having count(*)>1");
// $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$data = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
  $data = $row['course_id'];
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

but it only displaying one value and I don't why.

[image: output]

Hoping someone could help me.

Comment: If you only want the course id to appear once in your results try adding the DISTINCT keyword:-

SELECT DISTINCT course_id from enrol group by course_id having count(*)>1

Comment: `$data[] = $row['course_id'];`

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem, thank you to those who helped.

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT course_id from enrol group by course_id having count(*)>1");
// $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$data = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
  $data[] = $row['course_id'];
}
echo json_encode($data);
```